# How to explicitly reject an IPN request

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

In [the documentation for IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/), it says things like "Check email address to make sure that this is not a spoof".  But I cannot see what to do when that is the case, and how I tell PayPal I want to reject a transaction. E.g. do I sent back a 400 instead of a 200? Or alter the POST data in some other way?

Or do I just ignore the message? (The problem with that is that PayPal will keep re-trying, which is wasted bandwidth for us, but also means it takes longer for the user to hear about the payment failure.)

**Background:** I realize sending it back to PayPal and getting the `VERIFIED` message back handles most security issues. But in my case, there is some unique ID information in the `custom` field. If that is missing, or does not validate against the DB, I want to reject the payment. I want my customer to see it failed, so they know to go and use a fresh form. The alternative is to accept the payment, and then have to involve a manual process trying to work out who the payment came from, and then possibly do a manual refund. (Other reasons to do this might be that the inventory has sold out in the split second between them seeing a product on the site and clicking BUY.)

Comment: I agree with EJP. IPN is simply notifying you the payment has already happened. Rejecting an IPN will simply cause PayPal to resend it. If you want more control over the process (and make IPN irrelevant) then switch to Payments Pro, where you control how and when payments happen.

Comment: Upvoted because this is a good question and desirable feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The payment didn't fail. PayPal is notifying you that the payment succeeded: not asking you whether you want to accept it. You can't reject it at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

Simple send back a `200` code to let Paypal know you received the IPN, otherwise Paypal will try to send the IPN response repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

IPN is Instant Payment Notification. After the payment paypal notify you the result of the payment. Check if connection VERIFIED, and next if if the payment is Completed and mark the result in the database.

If you say to PayPal the ipn address in the cart, Paypal send you the notification. You can't say to paypal: "yes please, send me a notification" and when receive say "why you send this?" If you put ipn in cart form you can provide a ipn url with code 200, not 404. Or remove ipn value in the cart form

Comment: that wasn't the question, if some hacker changed the price in the cart on client side, and send a wrong payment request to paypal with a price of 0, then a hacked sale is being made and he can't inform paypal that this IPN had something wrong.