# Rejecting a PayPal IPN request for security reasons

Tags: security, paypal, paypal-ipn

When I get an IPN from PayPal (or a similar service) to indicate a sale, they ask to :

1. Send back `200 OK`
2. Send back the request body.

As you know the client can easily play with the numbers and set a price of 0, while ordering a product that cost 100$, or just get a spoof message with a fake sale.

In this case, they advice to check the `IPN` message on the cloud.
But at this stage the **sale has been made**, and if this was a hack, the seller will have to refund, and this whole scheme sounds wrong.

It seems that i can't really send `400` instead of `200 OK`.

I read this [How to explicitly reject an IPN request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248064/how-to-explicitly-reject-an-ipn-request) and turn out you can't really reject after you compared the payment request with your DB and found that something was wrong.

So how can i make sure the sale is authentic ?

Comment: don't use IPN, prepare a payment server side, then redirect the user to the URL the paypal api gives you back, and if the client accept the payment, then he will be redirected back to your server where you can approve the payment, and so there is no problem with this scenario

Comment: not sure what you offer at all, but i am making a payment on behalf ( like a marketplace) so personaA pay personB, I am just providing the service.

Comment: Ok i see what you say, but this sounds a little bit like a bad practice since all gateways works the other way . paypal's docs doesn't mention this option. Also, when i have the link for payment, i need to send it to client in order to redirect him, so this again not safe

Comment: well it's not, it's actually the Paypal's preferred way to accept payments, as you can read here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/paypal-payments/ as you can see there is the phase "Create PayPal payment.", then the " Get payment approval." and at the end there is "Execute payment.". However this is the best way to accept payment, like for ecommerce, where the receiver is always you, idk if you can do this also changing the receiver

Comment: 1. There is no sale until you have received the correct payment. 2. If your application flow is such that you execute the sale before you're received the money, fix it. FIx it quick before you go broke. 3. You are under no obligation to refund anything to a fraudster.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne thanks ! did you ever use IPN ? After client send a form, paypal send an IPN, at this point, even if i discovered a weird IPN price, i can't do nothing because when i got this IPN, it means that the sale HAS BEEN MADE and the receiver GOT A PAYPAL EMAIL that he had a sale. Which mean - that the receiver now has to deal with a fraud, and refund.

Comment: ** Why refund? because the buyer paid 50 instead of 100 (change the client price), and can always declare that he paid and it was a bug or something else like a discount. Now the seller has to answer PayPal and explain that his product doesn't cost 50 but 100. (and that's in a good case - if he ever notice that the price is wrong)

Comment: So the fraudster gave you $50. Thanks very much. There is no contract of sale. You didn't offer the goods at that price.Really in business terms you should *bill* him for the remaining $50. In any case what process can he possibly engage in to get it back? None. And yes I have used IPN, at great length. You're supposed to perform IPN verification to verify that the IPN came from Paypal, and you're supposed to use registered buttons to prevent the fraud of changing the value field in the HTML, and that also covers the matter of the explanation to PayPal, which is no longer required.

Comment: Basically you are looking for a programming solution to a business problem. You need to educate yourself more about the business and accounting and legal implications of this situation, and also about what Paypal IPN and hosted buttons already provide in the way of security.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use a [server-side front end UI](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) paired with two routes on your server to 'Set Up Transaction' and 'Capture Transaction'": https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/ .  Then you do not need IPN at all, for anything.

---

However, if you are going to use IPN, it is documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/

There is a verification step where you ***post the IPN message back to PayPal*** to check whether it is valid or not. This answers your question.

---

If what you want to accomplish is refuse the transaction due to an invalid amount or description, at this point it is already too late in the case of a sale type transaction. All you can do is issue a refund via API.

Comment: "There is a verification step where you post the IPN.." that's exactly the problem, at this point the sale is made. Which makes me think : what did the engineers in PayPal think? seriously, why couldn't you send me IPN to approve first? and then confirm the sale? it is so obvious that clients can change front end, so ... ?

Comment: IPN is not designed for that, it's simply an add-on notification service of transaction statuses.  If you want to decide whether or not to capture a transaction, see my first paragraph above about the server-side integration, which again is what you *should* be using.